# React - undefined properties of object after destructuring

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api, destructuring

I am trying to render a list of objects after a fetch, I get all the data, but at render time, properties are undefined. What am I doing wrong? Here is my code.

```
import React from 'react';

const Post = (post) => {
    const {id, userId, title, body} = post;
    console.log(post); // good
    console.log(post.title); // undefined
    return (
        <li key={post.id}>
            <div>{title}</div>
            <div>{body}</div>
        </li>
    );
};

export default Post;
```

[image: here is the console]

Comment: post.post.title and destructre like `{post:{id, userId, title, body}} = post`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to destructure the incoming props as well:

```
import React from 'react';

const Post = ({ post }) => { // here
    const { id, userId, title, body } = post;
    console.log(post); // good
    console.log(post.title); // undefined
    return (
        <li key={post.id}>
            <div>{title}</div>
            <div>{body}</div>
        </li>
    );
};

export default Post;
```

Remember that using something like this:

```
<Post post={...} />
```

is like this:

```
Post({ post: { ... } });
```